# WPF print UIElement / Scroller multipage prints same page always

Tags: wpf, printing, uielement

I'm trying to print a scroller a `UIelement`, or anything multipage for that matter.

I've inherited from `DocumentPaginator`, and it prints, it even prints the right amount of pages.

The trouble is it keeps printing the first page, over and over.

Here is my paginator:

```
   public class MyPaginator : DocumentPaginator {
    ScrollViewer _printStuff;

    public MyPaginator(ScrollViewer document, PaperSize pageSize) {
        _printStuff = document;
        _pageSize.Height = 100; //pageSize.Height;
        _pageSize.Width = 100; //pageSize.Width;
    }

    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber) {
        _printStuff.ScrollToVerticalOffset((PageSize.Height * pageNumber));
        _printStuff.UpdateLayout();
        DocumentPage dp = new DocumentPage(_printStuff);
        return dp;
    }

    public override bool IsPageCountValid {
        get { return true; }
    }

    private int _pageCount;
    public override int PageCount {
        get {
            if (_pageCount == 0) {
                this.ComputePageCount();
            }
            return _pageCount;
        }
    }
    private Size _pageSize;
    public override Size PageSize {
        get {
            return _pageSize;
        }
        set {
            _pageSize = value;
        }
    }

    public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override void ComputePageCount() {
        //base.ComputePageCount();

        var totalHeight = 0d;

        if (totalHeight == 0) {
            totalHeight = _printStuff.DesiredSize.Height;
        }

        var pc = (totalHeight / PageSize.Height);
        _pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(pc);

    }

}
```

And here is my calling code:

```
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        var paginator = new MyPaginator(scroller, ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize);

        printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "My Receipt");
```

and here is my user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestVBS.Views.PrintTest2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Name="myBox">

<ScrollViewer Name="scroller">
    <Grid Name="layout">

       <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="94,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

            <TextBlock>HEllow </TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>HEllow</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>adsfas</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</TextBlock>

            <TextBlock>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Why won't it print the second, third and fourth pages?

Comment: Hi Smithy,

Did you manage to find a solution to this by any chance?

Comment: I found a few examples online and mish mashed them together. http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/20/wpf-printing-part-2-the-fixed-document.aspx these tuts helped alot